# Pull out only two variables from a column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R for which one column has multiple variables.  The variables either start with ABC, DEF, GHI.  Those variables are followed by a series of 6 numbers (ie ABC052689, ABC062895, DEF045158).

For each row, i would like to pull one instance of ABC (the one with the largest number).

If the row has ABC052689, ABC062895, DEF045158, I would like it to pull out ABC062895 because it is greater than ABC052689.

I would then want to do the same for the variable that starts with DEF######.

I have managed to filter the data to have rows where ABC is there and either DEF or GHI is there:

```
library(tidyverse)
data_with_ABC <- test %>% 
  filter(str_detect(car,"ABC"))

data_with_ABC_and_DEF_or_GHI <- data_with_ABC %>% 
  filter(str_detect(car, "DEF") | str_detect(car, "GHI"))
```

I don't know how to pull out let's say ABC with the greatest number

```
ABC052689, ABC062895, DEF045158 -> ABC062895
```

Comment: To be clear: dataframe `test` contains one column, `car`, where each row of that column is the comma-separated string?

Comment: Yes @neilfws you are correct.  dataframe 'test' contains one column 'car' where each row contains a comma-separated string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a base R solution, we can try using `lapply` along with `strsplit` to identify the greatest `ABC` plate in each CSV string, in each row.

```
df <- data.frame(car=c("ABC052689,ABC062895,DEF045158"), id=c(1),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df$largest <- lapply(df$car, function(x) {
    cars <- strsplit(x, ",", fixed=TRUE)[[1]]
    cars <- cars[substr(cars, 1, 3) == "ABC"]
    max <- cars[which.max(substr(cars, 4, 9))]
    return(max)
})
df

                            car id   largest
1 ABC052689,ABC062895,DEF045158  1 ABC062895
```

Note that we don't need to worry about casting the substring of the plate number, because it is fixed width text.  This means that it should sort properly even as text.

Comment: thanks @Tim Biegeleisen, I didn't phrase my question correctly.  the column car contains a comma separated string that could have multiple instances of ABC, DEF and or GHI

Comment: since I am new to R, I am trying to figure out what each steps does and most of it is pretty clear except the '[[1]]' part in the strsplit function.  I see it in the R documentation for strsplit but it's not defined

Comment: @rdavis `strsplit` returns a list, so `[[1]]` says to access the first element in the list, which is the one containing the vector of split terms.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Tim's answer, if you want to do all ABC/DEF at one time, following code may help with `library(tidyverse)`:

```
> df <- data.frame(car=c("ABC052689", "ABC062895", "DEF045158", "DEF192345"),                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> 
> df2 = df %>% 
+     mutate(state = str_sub(car, 1, 3), plate = str_sub(car, 4, 9))
> 
> df2
        car state  plate
1 ABC052689   ABC 052689
2 ABC062895   ABC 062895
3 DEF045158   DEF 045158
4 DEF192345   DEF 192345
> 
> df2 %>% 
+   group_by(state) %>% 
+   summarise(maxplate = max(plate)) %>% 
+   mutate(full = str_c(state, maxplate))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  state maxplate full     
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>    
1 ABC   062895   ABC062895
2 DEF   192345   DEF192345
```

Comment: thanks @liuminzhao , I didn't phrase my question correctly.  the column car contains a comma separated string that could have muliple instances of ABC, DEF and or GHI

Comment: @rdavis, then you can use `read_csv` to import your csv file and convert to dataframe first.